# Sudden increase in direct (not set) traffic after implementing Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

After I installed Google Tag Manager, there has been a big increase in direct traffic with "(not set)" landing page. When I look at the events, they're all now coming from (not set) landing page.

So it looks like events are firing, but _trackpageview is not. However, I have bot Page View and Events in GTM Firing on "all pages". There are not view filters on the page, so this is not the case either. And when I use GTM's debug functionality, all tags seem to be firing correctly. This has been an issue for a couple of weeks now, ever since I implemented GTM.

Comment: The last time that happend to me I had used custom HTML tags for both pageviews and events. Since the event tracking tag created a new instance of the GA tracker all events where recorded without landing page or other associated data. So check if you are somehow creating multiple instances of the tracker object (should not be the case if you use tag templates unless you enter a name for the tracker with different values in both tags).

Comment: I'm using Tag Templates, so this shouldn't be the case. I have implemented all events as instructed (firing rule is {{event}} equals gtm.click or gtm.linkClick and then there's spesific rule f.e. class or id). Click Listener and Link Click Listener are firing on all pages.

Comment: any chance a filter is blocking pageview hits ?

Comment: No, I'm not using filters.